# Ajax Issue When Using Tabs

Tags: php, ajax

Im trying to display a table using the ajax. It only appeared in First Tab (Time) as in picture below. But when click on Tab (Agent) nothing appeared. Check it with browser console, it says Error 500 on the request link.

[image: The Time Tab is Working. It display data]

[image: The Agent Tab Not Working. Got Error 500 in Console when Click on it]

The Code is as follow:

```
public function actionChartReports()
{   
    //dump($this->data);
    $data='';
    if ( $data=Driver::generateReports($this->data['chart_type'], $this->data['time_selection'],
       $this->data['team_selection'], $this->data['driver_selection'],
       $this->data['chart_type_option'],
       $this->data['start_date'],
       $this->data['end_date']
        )){             
    }       

    //dump($data);  

    $new_data=array();

    if (is_array($data) && count($data)>=1){

        $first_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data[0]['delivery_date']."-1 day"));
            $new_data[]=array(
               'date'=>$first_date,
               'successful'=>0,
               'cancelled'=>0,
               'failed'=>0
        );

        foreach ($data as $val) {
            //dump($val);
            switch ($val['status']) {

                case "successful":  
                $new_data[]=array(
                  'date'=>$val['delivery_date'],
                  'successful'=>$val['total'],
                  'driver_name'=>isset($val['driver_name'])?$val['driver_name']:'',
                  'total_order_amount'=>isset($val['total_order_amount'])?$val['total_order_amount']:'',

                );
                break;

                case "cancelled":   
                $new_data[]=array(
                  'date'=>$val['delivery_date'],
                  'cancelled'=>$val['total'],
                  'driver_name'=>isset($val['driver_name'])?$val['driver_name']:'',
                  'total_order_amount'=>isset($val['total_order_amount'])?$val['total_order_amount']:'',

                );
                break;

                case "failed":  
                $new_data[]=array(
                  'date'=>$val['delivery_date'],
                  'failed'=>$val['total'],
                  'driver_name'=>isset($val['driver_name'])?$val['driver_name']:'',
                  'total_order_amount'=>isset($val['total_order_amount'])?$val['total_order_amount']:'',

                );
                break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        /*$new_data[]=array(
          'date'=>date("Y-m-d"),
          'failed'=>0,
          'driver_name'=>''
        );*/
    }

    $table='';

    if ( $this->data['chart_type_option']=="agent"){

        ob_start();
        require_once('charts-bar.php');
        $charts = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        ob_start();
        require_once('chart-bar-table.php');
        $table = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

    } else {                                
        ob_start();
        require_once('charts.php');        
        $charts = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        ob_start();
        require_once('chart-table.php');            
        $table = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }       
    $this->code=1;
    $this->msg="OK";
    $this->details=array(
      'charts'=>$charts,
      'table'=>$table
    );
    $this->jsonResponse();
}
```

Im using PHP7.2 .Thanks